# Pulling value from a serialized array - Form Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-boot

I have a form:

```
<form role="form" id="emailForm" action="#" th:action="@{/emailSubmission}" th:object="${university}" method="post">
     <div class="form-group">

        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" ></input>
            <p>
                <label for="emailID"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailID" id="emailID" field="email" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="Enter email"></input></p>
            <p>
                <label for="uniID"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> University Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="uniID" id="uniID" field="uniName" th:field="*{uniName}" placeholder="Enter University Name"></input></p>
            <p>
                <label for="adminID"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Administrator name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="adminID" id="adminID" field="adminName" th:field="*{adminName}" placeholder="Enter Aministrator Name"></input></p>
     </div>
     <button type="button" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-default btn-success btn-block" data-dismiss="modal" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Register</button>
</form>
```

And some jQuery:

```
//submit form validation
$("#submitButton").click(function(event) {
    var form_data = $("#emailForm").serializeArray();
    var error_free = true;
    for (var input in form_data) {
        var element = $('#' + form_data[input]['name']);
        var valid = element.hasClass("is-valid");

        if (!valid) {
            error_free = false;
        }

    }
    if (!error_free) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        sendEmail();
    };

});
```

My problem is with the line:

```
var element=$('#' + form_data[input]['name']);
```

It'm trying to return $('#emailID') etc but can't seem to get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) is an empty element and must not have an end tag.

Comment: What do you get with a `console.log(form_data);` ?

Comment: Array(4)
0
:
{name: "id", value: "0"}
1
:
{name: "email", value: "test@uni.ac.uk"}
2
:
{name: "uniName", value: "aUni"}
3
:
{name: "adminName", value: "anAdmin"}

@MickaelLeger

Comment: @MickaelLeger I get it now. My hidden field 'id' doesn't have the 'is-valid' class. Thanks!

Comment: So you want to get `$('#emailID');` but here I can't see it, is it normal or I miss something? Your "name" look like your "field" attr and not your "name", no? @Hughes_J

Comment: Try somehting like this maybe `$("input[field='+ form_data[input]['name'] + ']")` ?

Comment: 'Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input['field'=id]' @MickaelLeger

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165586/discussion-between-mickael-leger-and-hughes-j). @Hughes_J

Comment: You say you want to lookup '#emailID', but your array log has 'email' in it.  Verify that your name and id attributes match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking with you in the comment, here is the output of your `form_data` var :

```
Array(4) 
    0 : {name: "id", value: "0"} 
    1 : {name: "email", value: "test@uni.ac.uk"} 
    2 : {name: "uniName", value: "aUni"} 
    3 : {name: "adminName", value: "anAdmin"}
```

According to your HTML, it refered to your "field" attr and not your "name", so to select them, change this :

```
var element = $('#' + form_data[input]['name']);
```

to this :

```
var element = $("input[field='" + form_data[input]['name'] + "']");
```

or this (as suggested in the comment by @Taplar) :

```
var element = $('input').filter('[field="'+ form_data[input]['name'] +'"]');
```

Is it ok for you?

Comment: I'm slightly confused by this answer.  `$("input").attr("field", form_data[input]['name']);`  isn't a selector.  It's an update to **all** input elements to change their field attribute.

Comment: @Taplar I'm ok with you, we were talking when he told me it's was good but you are right it should change the attr value and not select it ! I edit with new anwser, it should works no? Can we select like this?

Comment: A selector to match on field would be either `$('input[field="'+ form_data[input]['name'] +'"])` or `$('input').filter('[field="'+ form_data[input]['name'] +'"]')` or a variation thereof.